# Running 2 publish profiles at same time?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I have 2 production servers that I need to deploy my app to every time.  Right now I have 2 different publish profiles - 1 for each server.  I run these manually through Visual Studio 2012 web deploy.

Is there a way to automate running both publish profiles in a single step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried writing a .bat file that deploys from the command line?  You should be able to put both in the one file and thereby run both with just a double click.  So the file would look something like:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln "/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DeployProduction1;Configuration=Prod;Password=pwd"

msbuild MySolution.sln "/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DeployProduction2;Configuration=Prod;Password=pwd"
```

As well as trial and error, I used the information from the following site, the section at the bottom labelled "Deploying from the Command Line":
[Tiny Happy Features #3 - Publishing Improvements, chained Config Transforms and Deploying ASP.NET Apps from the Command Line](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx)

Comment: I think this may work - however I can't seem to get my web.config transformations to work correctly.  If I publish via command line I get a different web.config than if I publish using Visual Studio

Comment: I'm wondering if part of the issue is that the <LastUsedBuildConfiguration> is inside of the publishProfile.User file.  Is that not accounted for through MSBuild?

Comment: We use MSBuild on Bamboo for publishing instead of MSBuild on the commandline, but I expect they work the same.  A couple quirks I found while doing this:

**1)** I had to put double quotes around the whole /p argument or not all of the options would actually be applied
**2)** We use the specific project's file instead of the solution file to prevent grabbing erroneous things for the deploy
**3)** To get transforms to work correctly we had to use both PublishProfile and Configuration

Comment: So the command I use looks like this:

`msbuild Amp.Web.Platform.csproj "/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=QC_Profile;Configuration=QC;MvcBuildViews=false"`

And my web.config has transform files, one of which is named web.QC.config

Comment: I edited the solution with two of the tips from the last comment